# Why do some 3.5" HDDs have a different height to others?

Tags: hard-drive

This has puzzled me for years. Now I'm finally asking about it.

In "modern times", surely there have only been two physical HDD sizes: 2.5" ("laptop disks") and 3.5" (big fat ones of the same dimensions as the old ones where we used IDE cables instead of SATA)?

**BUT** I have two different 3.5" HDDs which have different **heights**!

Both are modern enough to use SATA, so it's not a difference between the "classic" old ones and the more modern ones.

I spent significant time searching but these are the best photos I could find, which don't really show the difference. However, I assure you that I have held the two disks in my hands just minutes ago and compared them side by side. One of them *definitely* has a different height, and I mean a significant difference.

The exact models are:

- **Seagate ST3250318AS** ( https://www.disctech.com/SCASite/product_images/ST3250318AS_1000-3.jpg?resizeid=11&resizeh=1200&resizew=1200 )
- **WD WD2500AAJS-75M0A0** ( https://www.disctech.com/SCASite/product_images/WD2500AAJS-DEL_1000-4.jpg?resizeid=11&resizeh=1200&resizew=1200 )

I've searched all over for info but cannot find any mention of different-heighted 3.5" disks.

Wouldn't changing the size mess with all the existing setups which assume certain dimensions?

Comment: Cost of production vs number of platters come in to play. As mounting holes on rear and bottom of sides, the height is not very important in fitting drives.

Comment: 2.5" drives come in different heights as well.  As long as the screwholes fit the standard mounts, it doesnt matter.

Comment: @Keltari there are even 2.5" drives that are larger than the standards and come with a warning that it will not fit in every device. Luckily this is not the case for 3.5" drives, but there's no reason that will never happen if we reach a capacity where that is necessary to advance.

Comment: Also, it might be that server enterprise disks might be smaller in height in order to fit a mounting mechanism for specific servers.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it fits the same standard slots is it the height relevant?

**No, definitely not.**

Isn't it possible for different manufacturers to come up with different solutions for the actual hardware inside (platters, assembly, etc.) to have different dimensions or density while still SATA complaint?

**Yes, definitely**, we've seen many different ones already and some designed for specific applications.

Why is this even a question?